# Swift protocol to require properties as protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I am trying to define a protocol "Repository" which requires de definition of a couple of properties (which implement a specific protocol "DataSource")

But due to the complexity of my real scenario one of this properties need to be a subprotocol of "DataSource".

I reduced the problem to this simple code:

```
protocol DataSource { }

protocol ExtraDataSouce: DataSource {
    func method1() -> String
}

struct MyDataSource: ExtraDataSouce {
    func method1() -> String {
        return "whatever"
    }
}


protocol Repository {
    var firstDataSource: DataSource { get }
    var secondDataSource: DataSource { get }
}

struct MyRepository: Repository {
    var firstDataSource: DataSource
    var secondDataSource: MyDataSource
}
```

Which return an error at compilation time because "MyRepository" doesn't conform "Repository". But I think it actually does... Any idea about why it doesn't accept "secondDataSource" in "MyRepository" defined as "MyDataSource" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Repository protocol implement 2 variable of DataSource type, when you are trying to modify a type of variable in struct that conforms to Repository protocol it won't let you do this because of required type. You should to use an associatedtype to make this change

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype type = DataSource
    var firstDataSource: DataSource { get }
    var secondDataSource: type { get }
}
```

Comment: Because secondDataSource var with DataSource type will require strongly to implement only this type. With associatedtype it let you implement a object of Datasource type.

Comment: Please include the explanation in the answer. You should always include an explanation in your answer, not just post code.

Comment: Do line `associatedtype type = DataSource` equivalent to line `associatedtype type`? I never met this usage of `associatedtype`. I have same result for both lines: in `MyRepository` I can now specify any type for `secondDataSource` that I want, `String` for example. Please, explain more wide if you can. I understand `associatedtype` main concept, but I am not sure that this is result that author was want to achieve

Comment: The idea is that you can define a protocol with functions or variables that take in a type that is defined by the object that uses that protocol. In fact associatedtype is a Placeholder for an Unknown Type.

Answer (score 2):

After searching I found this information about your question (please, correct me if I wrong somewhere or if I miss something):

Even while logically your code should work, swift compiler don't separate cases when you use regular or read- only protocol variables when you declaring their type in your `MyRepository` class. On other words, error in your code become obvious if you will write in `Repository`

```
var secondDataSource: DataSource { get set }
```

and compiler don't separate this case. I did not found fully right way to do what you want. But there is two close ways:

1) Obvious and probably most right way - change `secondDataSource` type in `MyRepository`, and use additional variable if you wish:

```
var _secondDataSource: MyDataSource
var secondDataSource: DataSource {
        get {return _secondDataSource}
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue as? MyDataSource else {
                fatalError("MyRepository: attempt to set DataSource type, MyDataSource type expected")
            }
            _secondDataSource = newValue
        }
    }
```

2) Associated type in protocol way. Here I will improve @RaduNunu answer, since `associatedtype type = DataSource` line in his code have only placeholder effect, and his solution allows you to choose on adoption any type of `secondDataSource` ever, `String` for example:

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype Type = DataSource
    var firstDataSource: DataSource { get }
    var secondDataSource: Type { get }
}

struct MyRepository: Repository {
    var firstDataSource: DataSource
    var secondDataSource: String // - this is ok!
}
```

This code will compile and work, but it looks pretty bad. Instead type placeholder you better use protocol conformance:

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype Type: DataSource
    var firstDataSource: DataSource { get }
    var secondDataSource: Type { get }
}

struct MyRepository: Repository {
    var firstDataSource: DataSource
    //var secondDataSource: String - this line not allowed now
    var secondDataSource: MyDataSource
}
```

This code already pretty close to goal. However, from now you can't use a protocol as associated type, so declaration

```
var secondDataSource: DataSource
```

in `MyRepository` will not work. This is pay for using associated type: you can use only `DataSource` conformed class/enum/struct types.