# Protocol implementation and inheritance

Tags: swift

I have two protocols and two classes implementing them as following :

```
protocol IMessage { }

class Message: IMessage { }

protocol IConversation {
    var messages: [IMessage] { get set }
}

class Conversation: IConversation {
    var messages: [Message] = []
}
```

With this code, I got the error « Type 'Conversation' does not conform to protocol IConversation »

Comment: Please do not change declarations in your post, it's cause problems with written answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in difference between `IMessage` and `Message` types. `IConversation` protocol expect that you are able assign to property `messages` variable with any type of `[IMessage]`, not only case `[Message]`. Simple example with one more class:

```
class OtherMessage: IMessage { }
```

By protocol declaration you should be able to assign variable with type `[OtherMessage]` to `messages`, and class `Conversation` don't allow this. Fix it:

```
class Conversation: IConversation {
    var messages: [IMessage] = []
}
```

**Update**: if you need to work with `Message` type, you can use, for example, this solution:

```
class Conversation: IConversation {
    var messages: [IMessage] {get{return _messages}set{_messages = newValue as! [Message]}}
    var _messages: [Message] = []
}
```

and work with `_messages` inside class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if my class `Conversation` is built to work only with `Message`, all I can do is to check the type and throw an error if it's another implementation of `IMessage` ?

Comment: @Morniak basically yes. You can use other property in your class (check update). Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007881/swift-protocol-to-require-properties-as-protocol) question could be related

Answer (score 1):

Your message types don't match. Your protocol requires `messages` of a type `[IMessage]`. You're declaring it in the class with `[Message]`.